# R DT Limit Editable Content by Type

Tags: r, dt

I have a shiny app that uses `DT` and its editable functionality.
The app works fine, but I want to limit/verify the user to input only numeric values, is this possible or do I have to check the values manually?

## MWE

Target: limit columns 1:2 to be numeric.

```r
DT::datatable(iris, 
              editable = list(target = "column", 
                              disable = list(columns = 3:ncol(iris))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a [pull request](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/pull/836) on the Github repository of `DT` which implements this feature. It is not accepted yet, hopefully it will be. In the meantime, you can restrict the editing to accept only numbers if you use my [fork of DT](https://github.com/stla/DT). To install it: `remotes::install_github("stla/DT", ref = "numericedit")`. To request the numeric editing for some columns, set the option `editable = list(target = "cell", numeric = INDICES)`, where `INDICES` is the vector of the indices of the columns for which you want the numeric editing. By default (if you don't set the `numeric` option), all numeric columns are restricted to the numeric editing. To disable this behavior, set `numeric = "none"`.